# Function not working for innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that moves some divs onclick of div class "close". This works fine initially, but I edit the content of those divs with output.innerHTML, and when I do so, the script doesn't work onclick anymore.

Javascript:

```
$(function()
{
       var open = true;
       $('.close').click(function() {
            if (open = true)
            {
                $("#upper").animate({'top' : '0px'}, {duration : 400});
                open = true;

                $("#lower").animate({'top' : '0px'}, {duration : 400});
                open = true;

                $("#filler").animate({'top' : '0px'}, {duration : 400});
                open = true;
            }
            else {
            }
       }); 
});
```

Also:

```
function enable() {
  var output = document.getElementById("passwordinfo");
  var sentence = '<h4>RE-ENABLE HMS MEDHOST ACCOUNT</h4>' + 
         '<div class="close" onclick="close()"></div>';
  var open = true;
  output.innerHTML = sentence;
}
```

The function "enable" inputs the html in the div fine, but onclick of .close doesn't work anymore. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Just to be sure you only have one of each #upper, #lower and #filler right? ID's are meant to be unique, if there is more than one present JS will pick (I want to say the first it sees but it might be the last). Also lose the onClick your jQuery is operating on the class anyway it's irrelevant and could be confusing later on. Also you're checking if open is true, then setting open to true, I assume you mean to set it false after closing the divs. And finally open = true is SETTING open. You want if(open==true) or simply if(open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the enable function you can re-add the click event:

```
function enable() {
var output = document.getElementById("passwordinfo");
var sentence = '<h4>RE-ENABLE HMS MEDHOST ACCOUNT</h4><div class="close" onclick="close()"></div>';
var open = true;
output.innerHTML = sentence;
$('.close').off('click')
$('.close').click(function()
    {
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

I probably doesn't work because you add a html after you add the click event. Don't forget to use the .off('click'), otherwise the event fires twice for element that were already in the dom when you added the event for the first time

Answer (score 1):

You should use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for dynamically added elements in DOM. Also the `if` condition is wrong.

Try this:

```
$(function()
{
       var open = true;
       $(document).on("click", ".close", function() {
            if (open)
            {
                $("#upper").animate({'top' : '0px'}, {duration : 400});
                open = true;

                $("#lower").animate({'top' : '0px'}, {duration : 400});
                open = true;

                $("#filler").animate({'top' : '0px'}, {duration : 400});
                open = true;
            }
            else {
            }
       }); 
});
```